# How to pass a various number of parameters to .properties file for message?

Tags: java

I am using Tapestry and want to pass a various number of parameters to .properties file to print out messages on screen.

For example, I want to print the message out like this:

- Messages are 1, 2, 3, and 4. or
- Messages are 1 and 2. or
- Messages are 1.

How would I define messages in properties file so that a various number of parameters can be passed? Can I pass them in list?

```
message=The messages for {0} - {1, list}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tapestry provides a `org.apache.tapestry.ioc.Messages` service (in tapestry-ioc) which you can inject in any component to:

- access any property specified in the `.properties` file attached to this component (method `String get(String key)`),
- get and use a `MessageFormatter` object to do a kind of "String.format(...)" of a property of this same file.

On Java side, in a component class, what you can do to build a message the way you want is:

```
public class MyComponent {

    @Inject
    private Messages messages;

    @Property
    private String messageToDisplay;

    @SetupRender
    final void init() {
        // ...
        messageToDisplay = messages.get("some-key").format(valueForParam0, valueForParam1, ...);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Moreover, up from v5.3 of Tapestry, you can use the `org.apache.tapestry5.alerts.AlertManager` service to easily display messages as alerts (with level like "info", "warn", etc.).